# How to create a new branch that has only my changes from develop but doesn't reflect any of my commits on my current branch

Tags: git

Due to how we have automagically handled deploying through our *many* kubernetees clusters when I'm doing development I'm doing it on my personal branch instead of a branch named after the bug (it's easier to automate deploying and view it on a branch I regularly maintain).  I also find myself occasionally doing pointless commits not because I think the code is in a good state but because I need to trigger a new automated deploy.

The net result is I end up with a personal branch with good working code, but with a bunch of ugly/pointless commits cluttering up it's history.  I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to move from my personal branch to the bug branch I'll do the merge request on?  I want to transfer all my code changes, but not any of the commit history since I last split off from develop.

Is there a quick/clean way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to rebase?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all your changes in a branch as a single commit into another one:

```
git checkout bugbranch
git merge --squash mybranch
git commit
```

If you need more control over the commit history, refer to:
[How do I squash my last N commits together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/how-do-i-squash-my-last-n-commits-together)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to leave the history on branch `personal`, but copy all the changes over to branch `bug` as a single commit.

```
git switch bug
git cherry-pick -n ..personal
git commit
```

That cherry-pick command takes all the changes on `personal` that aren't on `bug` and applies them to `bug` without (due to `-n`) committing. Then you can commit them all as a single commit with a new message.

If `personal` wasn't branched off `bug`, then you might want to modify the cherry-pick to better control which changes it picks. This takes all changes made on `personal` since it branched from `develop`:

```
git cherry-pick -n develop..personal
```